# Drag and drop between the extjs panels

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs5

I want to implement drag and drop buttons between the panels. Can this be done in a simple way? [I did example on Ext.ux.BoxReorderer](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rvg):

```
Ext.require(['Ext.ux.BoxReorderer']);

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: "pnl1",
            plugins: Ext.create("Ext.ux.BoxReorderer"),
            layout: {
                type: "hbox"
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: "button",
                text: "btn1"
            },{
                xtype: "button",
                text: "btn2"
            },{
                xtype: "button",
                text: "btn3"
            }]
        });

        Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: "pnl2",
            plugins: Ext.create("Ext.ux.BoxReorderer"),
            layout: {
                type: "hbox"
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: "button",
                text: "btn1"
            },{
                xtype: "button",
                text: "btn2"
            },{
                xtype: "button",
                text: "btn3"
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

But do not know how to implement drag and drop between the panels.

P.S. ExtJS version is 5.x.x

Comment: Did you see the examples in kitchensink? http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#drag-drop

Comment: Yes, grid d'n'd is easier. Panel requires animation.

Comment: I don't know of a plugin that allows what you are looking for but here is how the low level implementation would look like for something more customised   https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/drag_drop.html @madreason